# Trying to make an alias for an .exe - Powershell saying it cannot resolve the alias

Tags: powershell, github, powershell-1.0

Some backgroudn: I'm learning GitHub through the Udacity "How to Use Git and GitHub" class. They tell me I need to use Command Line, not Windows' native command prompt. I've installed GitHub, which appears to install Git Shell which runs Powershell. I want to create a shortcut to run Notepad++, and I used the following command:

```
new-item alias:ntpd -value 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad.exe'
```

Everything seems to work fine. It comes up with a little table showing the CommandType, Name, and Definition. The program should open when I type the alias. But when I type:

```
ntpd
```

I get the following error:

> Cannot resolve alias 'ntpd' because it refers to term 'C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad.exe', which is not recognized as a
>   cmdlet, function, operable program, or script file. Verify the term
>   and try again.

I'm very new to Powershell and really can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure `C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad.exe` exists. Try a `Test-Path "C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad.exe"` and see the outcome. Also, instead of `New-Item`, just use `New-Alias`

Comment: I did the Test-Path as you recommend, and it returned False! But I can clearly see the .exe in my Windows browser! Is there something I'm not getting?

Comment: Are you sure it's "Program Files (x86)" and not "Program Files". PowerShell has tab completion, so enter `New-Alias -Name ntpd -Value C:\\` and then tab till you find notepad.exe

Comment: Yea, I'm still not sure what's going on. Here's a screenshot of what I tried:
http://i.imgur.com/TFTeuhJ.png

Comment: You have an unnecessary backtick. Don't just copy and paste. That'll get you no where. Actually type it in.

Comment: Aha! Ok, I didn't copy and paste, I actually typed it. I think you were trying to do code formatting but it didn't display in my browser. I only saw backticks. Anyway, I typed it in right this time and it worked! Thanks for your help!

Comment: One more question - After I close the shell and reopen it, the alias doesn't work! Any idea why?

Comment: Nevermind! I figured it out! I need to make a Powershell Profile! This guide explained it easy enough: http://www.howtogeek.com/50236/customizing-your-powershell-profile/